# Simple countdown timer with a value

Tags: jquery

```js
function startTimer(duration, text, value) {
  var timer = duration,
    minute, second, value;
  setInterval(function() {
    minute = parseInt(duration/ 60, 10);
    second = parseInt(duration% 60, 10);
    if (minute < 10) {
      minute = "0" + minute;
    } else {
      minute = minute;
    }
    if (second < 10) {
      second = "0" + second;
    } else {
      second = second;
    };
    text.text(minute + ":" + second);
    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var duration = 1200,
    text = $('#time'),
    value = 10;
  minute = parseInt(duration/ 60, 10);
  second = parseInt(duration% 60, 10);
  if (minute < 10) {
    minute = "0" + minute;
  } else {
    minute = minute;
  }
  if (second < 10) {
    second = "0" + second;
  } else {
    second = second;
  };
  $("#time").text(minute + ":" + second);
  startTimer(duration, text, value);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Remain <span id="time"></span> minute</div>
```

I want to use a simple countdown timer. Firsty I define a duration I send the duration kind of seconds and minutes to span text. Also I define a value. For example value is 20. I want to decrease the value in every minute. When the value is equal zero function will be finished. I hope I could have explained enough.

Comment: Variable `sure` is/was undefined. I've cleaned up your code.

Comment: I edited my question that is duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a variable `elapsed` to keep track of how many seconds have past
- Deduct `value` when `elapsed` is divisible by 60, meaning a minute have past
- Call `run` once per second as long as `value` is greater than 0
- Also, you don't need to repeat the code in startTimer and onLoad

```js
function startTimer(duration, text, value) {
  var timer = duration,
    minute, second, value, elapsed = 0;

  var run = function() {
    minute = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    second = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    if (minute < 10) {
      minute = "0" + minute;
    } else {
      minute = minute;
    }
    if (second < 10) {
      second = "0" + second;
    } else {
      second = second;
    };
    text.text(minute + ":" + second);
    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
    elapsed++;
    if (elapsed % 60 == 0) value--;
    if (value <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }
    $("#time").text(minute + ":" + second);
    $('#val').text(value);

    if (value > 0) {
      setTimeout(run, 1000);
    }
  };
  
  run();
}

window.onload = function() {
  var duration = 1200,
    text = $('#time'),
    value = 10;

  startTimer(duration, text, value);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Remain <span id="time"></span> minute</div>
<div>Value <span id="val"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wonderfull. Thank you so much.

Comment: (elapsed % 60 == 0) it must be like this. Thanks again.